# Регулярное выражение в С++

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения

```
const tr1::regex rx("^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\.(0[13578]|1[02])\.((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\.(0[13456789]|1[012])\.((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\.02\.((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\.02\.((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$");
            tr1::smatch xResults;
            bool res = false;

            while (!res) {
                system("cls");
                cout << Lang::lang[31];
                getline(cin, temp);
                res = regex_match(temp,rx);
            }
```

Не могу понять почему не работает следующий код. В res всегда false. Тестил отдельно на сайте регулярное выражение, работает норм. В строке тоже всё нормально.

Comment: Регулярное выражение используется для валидации даты, в формате 04.12.1992

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала не пробовали вспомнить о том, что в C/C++ обратная косая черта в строке - служебный символ, так что `\d` надо записывать как `\\d`?

Comment: Там еще `\.` есть

Comment: Спасибо чувак) Огромное) Запарился слишком)